# CodeIgniter display last id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to display as a value of textbox the last id of my record and then increment it.

This is what I have:

**view.php**

```
          <?php 
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();
            $newId = $id + 1;
            $data = array(
                    'name'        => 'customercode',
                    'id'          => 'inputCustomerCode',
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'readonly'    => 'true',
                    'class'       => 'form-control',
                    'value'       => 'CUST0000' . $newId
            );
            echo form_input($data);
            ?>
```

But it's just displaying **CUST00001**? What am I doing wrong in here? Help is much appreciated and needed. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you have many records?

Comment: @raheelshan Yes I have 11 records in my database

Comment: you can't call `$this->db->insert_id();` directly in view. For this variable you must execute mysql insert query and get this variable right after it.

Comment: Do you have insert query before calling  $this->db->insert_id(); ?

Comment: Can you please show your insert query here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get last inserted id with `$this->db->insert_id();` if you want to use this for multiple places, please take this in a variable and use that variable.

you can use `$this->db->insert_id()` after insert query.

```
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

you can use a simple query to get max id

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX (id) FROM table");
$id = $query->row()->id;
```

and use $id in form

```
 'value'       => 'CUST0000' . $id + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$id = $this->db->insert_id();` you may use following code:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$id = $query->row()->id;

$newId = $id + 1;

$data = array(
   'name'        => 'customercode',
   'id'          => 'inputCustomerCode',
   'type'        => 'text',
   'readonly'    => 'true',
   'class'       => 'form-control',
   'value'       => 'CUST' . str_pad($id+1, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)
   );

echo form_input($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$this->db->insert_id()+1
```

You need to display `$newId`.
Make sure you have queried for the last Id. `$this->db->insert_id()` returns only when you have inserted some record. If you haven't , then you need to query to get the last inserted id. You can use this simple query.

```
SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**$this->db->insert_id()**

```
The insert ID number when performing database inserts.
```

Looked at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/database/helpers.html and the first function is `$this->db->insert_id();`

This also works with active-record inserts...